# Selecting random greeting from reading a JSON file using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file looking like this which i have to randomise so that every time any input comes it shows any random output from the 3 in the json file.

```
{
    "1":"Welcome",
    "2":"Hello",
    "3":"Hi"
}
```

I read the JSON file

```
greeting_template1=readjson(input_file_path+'greeting_template1.json')

and to randomise

greeting_template1 = random.choice(greeting_template1)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
   greeting_template1 = random.choice(greeting_template1)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\lib\random.py", line 262, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 2
```

Please highlight where I am going wrong

Comment: This is not a valid JSON file. It should be `{ "1": "Welcome", "2": "Hello", "3": "Hi" }`.

Comment: Also I would question why you are using some function called `readjson` which seems to be throwing an error from a `yaml` parser rather than using the `json.loads` from standard library `json`

Comment: @PyPingu pardon it was formatting error. But the problem is it is not randomising as shown in error

Comment: It simply isn't clear what you're expecting to get back to be honest. `random.choice` isn't designed to work on a dictionary, hence your error. If you just want the word part then do `random.choice(list(greeting_template1.values()))`. I'd also probably not reassign `greeting_template1` to the result, seems unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @PyPingu Actually I am trying to build a mini chat bot where in when I press "hi" so from the Json it selects random of (hi,hello, welcome) everytime

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out your JSON is not valid.
Valid json file would be:

```
{
    "1":"Welcome",
    "2":"Hello",
    "3":"Hi"
}
```

And the code to get a random would look something like:

```
import json
import random

with open('greeting_template1.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

random_greeting = data[random.choice(list(data))]
```

The reason you are getting error is because random.choice() needs a sequence as an argument. Parsing a json gives you a python dictionary which is not a sequence.

Comment: ```random_greeting = data[random.choice(list(data))]``` returns string is it possible if to return the Json only the randomly selected json like ```{  "2":"Hello"}``` when i do ```random_greeting = random.choice(list(data.items()))``` it gives tuple ```("2":"Hello")``` which json.dumps is unable to convert in required format

Comment: You can get the python dict as follow:
`choice = random.choice(list(data));
random_greeting = {choice:data[choice]}`

Answer (score 0):

Your document has 3 JSONs in it, not one. Once you close the initial `{`, that is your JSON. You need to rewrite to:

```
{
    "1":"Welcome",
    "2":"Hello",
    "3":"Hi"
}
```

Comment: pardon it was formatting error. But the problem is it is not randomising as shown in error

Comment: ```random_greeting = data[random.choice(list(data))]``` returns string is it possible if to return the Json only the randomly selected json like``` { "2":"Hello"}``` when i do ```random_greeting = random.choice(list(data.items()))``` it gives tuple ```("2":"Hello")``` which json.dumps is unable to convert in required format